# Snippet with prefix "``" (double backtick) not working for inline Markdown code block

Tags: visual-studio-code, prefix, vscode-snippets

For writing inline Markdown code blocks quickly, I want to use the following snippet:

```
"prefix": "``",
"body": ["`$1` $2"],
```

This snippet would enable me to just tab through the code block.
The snippet however does not trigger when using ``.

If I try to escape the backticks with backslashes, the prefix ends up empty and doesn't work either.

```
"prefix": "\`\`",
"body": ["`$1` $2"],
```

[image]

Is it possible to use `` as a prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an explanation for why backticks work as a prefix but the snippet suggestion must be manually triggered with <kbd>Ctr/</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

From [snippets prefix support utf-8](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80532#issuecomment-529818554):

> The prefix can be anything but "suggestions as you type" are only
> triggered when typing a word character. What that is defines the
> corresponding language. For non word prefixes suggestion must be
> triggered manually, using ctrl+space

Backticks are apparently not word characters in markdown, so you need to manually trigger the suggestions with <kbd>Ctr/</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Otherwise this works:

```
"backticks": {
    "scope": "markdown",
    "prefix": "\\`\\`",      // note double backslashes
    "body": ["`$1` $2"],
}
```

[image: demo of using backticks as a prefix in a snippet]

Comment: Thank you. I managed to make it work eventually, without having to Ctrl+Space, by using BetterTouchTool to remap keybinds. I binded ` to trigger 1) ^ Space 2) Tab.